# The difference of having another layer of {} in sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say we have a set X

X = {∅,{a},{a,b},{a,b,c}}

And there are three different statements

{{a}} ∈ X

{a} ⊆ X

{{a}} ⊆ X

One or more of these statements is false, and I can't figure out which one

What is the difference between {a} and {{a}} ?

Comment: You can use the definition of equality for sets to show that $\{a\} \ne \{\{a\}\}$.  Try it.

Comment: Hint: Only one of the statements is true.

Answer (score 2):

Can you tell the difference between "a ball inside a box" and "a ball inside a box inside a bigger box"?

Then you should be able to tell the difference between $\{a\}$ and $\{\{a\}\}$.

Comment: A related question: Why can't {a}={{a}}?